# How to include a CSS stylesheet into an *included* PHP file?

Tags: php, html, css

I have an PHP/HTML main page, in which I include different other PHP files (I include them within the body of the main page).

What if I want to include a CSS stylesheet into only ONE of the included file?

What if that included file is a PHP-only file? (that is, it doesn't have those `<head>` tags, where the stylesheet reference is supposed to be)

What happens if I put "head" tags into a PHP file that is included in the body of the main page? I am wondering if putting head tags in the middle of the HTML body tags could cause problems at all, or at least with certain browsers.

Comment: php has nothing to do with css. php is "something" that generates html on server side.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I am wondering if putting head tags in the middle of the html Body tags could cause problems at all, or at least with certain browsers. Thanks

Comment: There should not be any head tags in the body of your document. Although it will probably work, don't do it. It's wrong.

Comment: Hi. Yes, but if I want to include a CSS file, where should I include it? In the head tags of the main page? Because I'm wondering if it could be considered as inefficient. Thanks

Comment: you can add css files or js anywhere in the body of the document. it will work but when somebody load it in a slow connection style and javascript will only work after the page has been loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it this way, after all of you includes you still get one html file at the end of it.  If you are including files in the body of your document, it should only contain tags that fit within the body, not html, head, title, body, etc.  Your css file should be loaded in the  of the main doc.  Something like this

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<!--
css and js here
-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- php include here ---->
<div>content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So after your includes the html should still be valid.  you can check that here http://validator.w3.org/

EDIT:
You can included as many css files as you want anywhere in the document but the overall structure should still be as above.  But try to consolidate your css files as much as possible.  Every external file is one more request the browser has to make, and can slow the load time if you have a lot.

Comment: Hi, I see what you mean. Thanks a lot for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can add style tags in the middle of your html, it's bad behaviour, but you can and it'll work. So, you can only import css you need depending on what you include to your main php. But, you don't have to put head tags for that.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok if you will put you link your css file in any of your files, also if your file is php, you can put your css before or after the php tag.  But for me its better to include your css file on your main page as long as you have a unique design or style for a unique element or id on the file that you want to design.

```
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php
 Content of your php file here
 ?>
```